# Reference for Envelope, Evolute and involute

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

I have to give a lecture on Envelopes, Evolute and Involute to I year undergraduate students. Please suggest me some books which explain these concepts with examples geometrically. Already I have seen wiki, very nice. But still I am very sure that, there should be some good lecture notes or books that covers these things nicely.

Thanks in Advance.